# pandas Data.frame assign issue

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to add new column by using the `.assign` function.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': range(1, 5), 'B': range(11, 15)})

def delta(df):

    df = df.assign(df_delta = df.A - df.B,
                   df_multiply = df_delta*30
                   )

    return df


print(delta(df))
```

but getting this error

> NameError: name 'df_delta' is not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or you can use a lambda to achieve this which can read the already assigned column:

```
def delta(df):
    df = df.assign(df_delta = df.A - df.B, df_multiply = lambda x : x['df_delta']*30)
    return df

print(delta(df))
```

---

```
   A   B  df_delta  df_multiply
0  1  11       -10         -300
1  2  12       -10         -300
2  3  13       -10         -300
3  4  14       -10         -300
```

Answer (score 1):

the `df_delta` column is not yet defined in the assign function, you can circumvent this error by temp variable:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': range(1, 5), 'B': range(11, 15)})

def delta(df):
    a_b = df.A - df.B
    df = df.assign(df_delta = a_b, df_multiply = a_b*30)
    return df

print(delta(df))
```

Prints:

```
   A   B  df_delta  df_multiply
0  1  11       -10         -300
1  2  12       -10         -300
2  3  13       -10         -300
3  4  14       -10         -300
```